# disable long press action of backspace button on Android?

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I have a search area (edittext) and i want to disable the long press action of backspace (delete) button. User must click this button for each characters to delete. How can i do it?

I'm new on it. Can you please edit comment lines?  On short press, i want default action; on long press, i want it to do what it does on short press.

```
 @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown( int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL ) {
      event.startTracking();
      return true; 
    }
    return super.onKeyDown( keyCode, event );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp( int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL ) {
      //Handle what you want on short press.      
      return true; 
    }

    return super.onKeyUp( keyCode, event );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyLongPress( int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL ) {
      //Handle what you want in long press.
      return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress( keyCode, event );
  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override [`onKeyDown`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)() method of your activity. You need to check for [KEYCODE_DEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_DEL) key.

Comment: i edited the question, can you please edit the comment lines on the code?
Thank you